# Ignore Angular.JS form validation for a single input inside a form

Tags: html, angularjs, forms

Is there any way I can do this? I have a form with like 5 inputs, but I want one of them, not to be affected by ngDirty or ngPrestine or any of that, is there anyway I can do this? If you need any more information, please tell me.

**Some HTML for context:**

```
  <input id="name" ng-model="device.Name" type="text" class="form-control">

  <input id="description" ng-model="img.Description" type="text" class="form-control" />    

</form>
```

**And CSS which was done by an outsider:**

```
input.ng-dirty
{
  &.ng-invalid
  {
    border: 1px solid $error;
    background-color: transparentize($error, 0.95);
  }
  &.ng-valid
  {
    border: 1px solid $success;
    background-color: transparentize($success, 0.95);
  }
}

input.ng-pristine
{
  &.ng-invalid
  {
    border: 1px solid $required;
    background-color: transparentize($required, 0.95);
  } 
}
```

Now basicly, this says that any input element when is on dirty or prestige state as those colors, how could I ignore that for a single field? Let's say for the 'name' field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding a css class that disables styling on input fields that use it.

The `:not()` CSS pseudo-class is perfect for this use.

**In CSS**

```
...

input.ng-pristine:not(.no-change) {
    ...
}

...
```

The styling will only apply on elements that doesn't have the class `no-change`.

**In HTML**

```
<input id="name" ng-model="device.Name" type="text" class="form-control no-change">
<input id="description" ng-model="img.Description" type="text" class="form-control" />
```